# Getting rid of keys in nested dictionary that contain None values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the following dict:

```
dict_2 = {
    'key1': {'subkey1': 2, 'subkey2': 7, 'subkey3': 5},
    'key2': {'subkey1': None, 'subkey2': None, 'subkey3': None},
}
```

I am looking forward to clean `dict_2` from those `None` values in the `subkeys`, by removing the entire key with its nested dict:

In short my output should be:

```
dict_2={key1:{subkey1:2,subkey2:7,subkey3:5}}
```

What I tried was :

```
glob_dict={}

for k,v in dict_2.items():
    dictionary={k: dict_2[k] for k in dict_2 if not None (dict_2[k]
['subkey2'])}
    if bool(glob_dict)==False:
        glob_dict=dictionary
    else:
        glob_dict={**glob_dict,**dictionary}

print(glob_dict)
```

My current output is :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I am not really sure if the loop is the best way to get rid of the `None` values of the nested loop, and I am not sure either on how to express that I want to get rid of the `None` values.

Comment: @IMCoins thank you for your response, however it continues outputting the same error after the change, I guess it has to do with: `dictionary={k: dict_2[k] for k in dict_2 if not None (dict_2[k]
['subkey2'])}`

Comment: You want to delete every subkey that is None, and delete the keys that have no subkeys left ?

Comment: I assume `dict_2={key1:{subkey1:None,subkey2:7,subkey3:5},key2:{subkey1:4,subkey2:None,subkey3:None}}` should result in `dict_2={key1:{subkey2:7,subkey3:5},key2:{subkey1:4}}`? So only keys are removed that don't have any subkeys left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A recursive solution to remove all `None`, and subsequent empty dicts, can look this:

#### Code:

```
def remove_empties_from_dict(a_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in a_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = remove_empties_from_dict(v)
        if v is not None:
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict or None
```

#### Test Code:

```
dict_2 = {
    'key1': {'subkey1': 2, 'subkey2': 7, 'subkey3': 5},
    'key2': {'subkey1': None, 'subkey2': None, 'subkey3': None},
}
print(remove_empties_from_dict(dict_2))
```

#### Results:

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': 2, 'subkey2': 7, 'subkey3': 5}}
```

Comment: `remove_empties_from_dict({}) == None`?

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_2={'key1':{'subkey1':2,'subkey2':7,'subkey3':5} ,'key2':{'subkey1':None,'subkey2':None,'subkey3':None}}

d = {}
for k, v in dict_2.iteritems():
    if any(v.values()):
        d[k] = v
print d
```

Result:

```
{'key1': {'subkey2': 7, 'subkey3': 5, 'subkey1': 2}}
```

Comment: In my Python 3 environment: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'". In my Python 2 console it returns an empty dictionary, if not all None values are under the same key.

Comment: Updated for python2.7

Comment: It still doesn't remove `None` subkeys, if there is another subkey in the same key section that is not set to `None`

Comment: @Mr.T python3 is dict.items() now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NestedDict`.

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

dict_2 = {
    'key1': {'subkey1': 2, 'subkey2': 7, 'subkey3': 5},
    'key2': {'subkey1': None, 'subkey2': None, 'subkey3': None},
}
nd = NestedDict(dict_2)
nd_filtered = NestedDict()

for key, value in nd.items():
    if value is not None:
        nd_filtered[key] = value
```

To get the result as a dictionary

```
>>> nd_filtered.to_dict()
{'key1': {'subkey1': 2, 'subkey2': 7, 'subkey3': 5}}
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and simplest way to solve this problem

my_d = {'a':1,'b':None,'c':2,'d':{'e':None,'f':3}}

**Code:**

```
my_n_d = {}
my_n1_d = {}
for i , j in my_d.items():
    if j is not None:
        my_n_d[i] = j
    if isinstance(j,dict):
        for key in j:
            if j[key] is not None:
                my_n1_d[key] = j[key]
                my_n_d[i] = my_n1_d
print(my_n_d)
```

**output:**
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': {'f': 3}}